# Iterating through a custom built array in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

In my view I wanted to mockup a collection of featured items.

I want to do something like

```
{{#each featuredItems}}
  {{title}}
{{/each}}
```

in my controller I have

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  featuredApps = [
    title: 'hi'
  ,
    title: 'Ok'
  ,
    title: "Three"
  ]
```

How do I iterate over this simply in my view? Right now I get this error:

```
Assertion failed: Expected hash or Mixin instance, got [object Array]
```

---

If I don't do it that way, then how would I do it if I added a feature flag to the Todo fixtures and wanted to iterate over a collection in the todos.hbs file specifically for featured and then below that show all of them?

Basically how do I do this

```
{{#each featured}}
  {{title}}
{{/each}}

{{#each}}
  {{title}}
{{/each}}
```

That puts the featured ones on the top and then everything all together in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use an if statement to check if an item is featured or not and then display it. Something like this:

```
<ul>
{{#each item in model}}
  {{#if item.featured}}
    <h1>{{item.color}}</h1>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

You can check this jsBin:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OTotazu/2/edit

Comment: you can try with setupController and set the context to the featured collection: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/